# Intermittent 403: Forbidden for google contacts groups pulling

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-contacts-api

I have a code in my App, which actually works properly to pull the google contact groups, However at few times this code breaks with forbidden error(403) in live environment.

```
GContacts::Client.new(
  access_token: token,
  default_type: :groups).all(params: { limit: MAX_LIMIT }).entries
```

Any idea why this is happening.

Thanks.

Comment: need to see the code.

Comment: Thanks @xlembouras for your reply, What I need to paste here more? and what code are you looking for. I am working on someone else's code. So if you can specify what you need I can try adding it here.

Comment: Do you perform a lot of subsequent calls to the service? Looks like they defend from DOSing their API.

Comment: Hmmmm. looks like you are right, @mudasobwa. is there any link that has these information based on which I can workout something.

Comment: I have no clue, but hopefully google has.

Comment: hmmmm. cool, thanks. I will check in that angle.